# regular expression in sublime text 2 to match text

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

I have a string that looks like this:

```
lonfksa.newsvine.com
```

and I have tons of file that looks like this:

```
http://ricambi.ru/avtomobilnie-novosti/lexus-gotovit-k-debiutu-obnovlenniy-rx
http://www.kiwibox.com/hoytboar/blog/entry/121424391/modis-tshirt-tips-untuk-womens-clothing/
http://www.euro-rockradio.com/archives/category/interview
http://lonfksa.newsvine.com/_news/2014/04/18/23538711-vampir-romantis-clothing
http://www.fam-hinterseer.de/cgi-bin/info.php?a%5B%5D=%3Ca+href%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.shopious.com%3Ecart+means+payment%3C%2Fa%3E
http://www.kiwibox.com/donniehihp/blog/entry/116146741/skin-care-beauty-makeup-tips-for-female/
http://www.kiwibox.com/karlagbr/blog/archive/2014/9/7/
```

I wanted to match the line that contains:

```
 lonfksa.newsvine.com
```

and I tried the following regex but it doesn't work:

```
(?s)lonfksa.newsvine.com(?s)
```

what regex should I use to match the whole line that has this string?

Comment: lonfksa.newsvine.com is enough to match line which contains lonfksa.newsvine.com

Comment: Why dont you try it out here? https://regex101.com/r/mX1oC5/1

Comment: @Rahul: Its not. Without escaping the dots it wont work.

Comment: @Rahul sometimes it has a http in front of it and some strings following it, I want to match the whole LINE

Comment: @C4ud3x: it is. The dot matches "any character".

Comment: @Jongware: Doh, yeah right. Need more coffee..

Comment: @aherlambang https://regex101.com/r/mX1oC5/3. But why commenting? Answer from stribizhev is right.

Comment: You can like `Shift + Cntrl + f ` and type the 'String' you want to find it will generate an file that will list the places where this match was found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of the multiline flag, and `^` and `$` anchors that will match at the string start and string end repsectively:

```
(?m)^.*lonfksa\.newsvine\.com.*$
```

Mind that you need to escape a dot in regex to make it match a literal dot. Your regex `(?s)lonfksa.newsvine.com(?s)` contains unescaped dots that match any character (even a newline since you are using a singleline inline option `(?s)`). The final inline option `(?s)` is not necessary, it does not do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex :

`^.*lonfksa\.newsvine\.com.*\b`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cX7cV0/3)

Comment: doesn't always have to be preceded with http basically I want to match the whole line

Comment: @aherlambang Edited, check now